# Printing an = symbol in my printf

Tags: c, printf

I am new to this and I am very sorry if this question is too simple but I am having a hard time finding it on either Google or here.

```
printf("The average is %.1f volts.\n", avg);
printf("10% = %.1f volts.\n", avg10);
printf("15% = %.1f volts.\n", avg15);
```

All I what to do is have it show the equals sign (=) on the screen, but it's giving me errors. Am I missing something? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

The problem has nothing to do with the `=`. It's the `%`; if you want to print an actual percent sign with printf, you need to use `%%` to distinguish it from a format specifier:

```
printf("10%% = %.1f volts.\n", avg10);

printf("15%% = %.1f volts.\n", avg15);
```